# How to avoid authentication when connecting to standalone chrome debug container?

Tags: docker, selenium, vnc-viewer, docker-selenium

I am using `selenium/standalone-chrome-debug`.

By default connecting to the container via VNC will trigger an authentication prompt which can be avoided by setting an environment variable as per the [documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium):

> If you want to run VNC without password authentication you can set the environment variable `VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1`.

When I start the container with the following command, I'm still prompted for the password:

```sh
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 0:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
```

As you can see in the following screencast:

- I'm still asked for a password
- Trying to authenticate without password fails
- When I use the default password (`secret`), it passes

**Question:** how do I avoid authentication completely?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding

> ```
>   VNC_NO_PASSWORD: 1
> ```

to the `environment` of the relevant service in docker-compose.yml worked for me.

Comment: For future visitors: this was changed to require `SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD: 1` as of around tag 4.2.2-20220622. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/pull/1603

Answer (score 0):

```
services:
 firefox:
  image: node-firefox:4.16.1-20231219
  shm_size: 2gb
  depends_on:
   - selenium-hub
  environment:
   - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
   - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
   - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
   - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD= true
```